# POST call to server stuck

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I have a very strange issue with one of our users: when he tries to save data (via ODataModel `create` method), there is a call to the service (like, `/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSERVICE_NAME_SRV/`) which stays in status "pending" in the browser's "Network" tab and nothing happens.

If I do double click on this line in the Network tab, a new tab opens with same URL and it works fine - I see the service's details.

User can do GET calls and he gets data.

If I log on with my credentials on this user's computer, I have the same issue.

Apparently, it's something with his computer/browsers, but I cannot figure out what exactly. The problem persists on all available browsers - Mozilla/Chrome/IE.

I tried to clear browsing data/restart the computer/whatever - nothing helps.

Does anyone know what happens here?

Thanks.

[image: This is how it looks in Network tab]

Comment: It's probably not pending forever. What error are you getting eventually? Did you set a breakpoint in the backend to see how far you get? Did you check the log transactions? `ST22` + `/IWBEP/ERROR_LOG` +  `/IWFND/ERROR_LOG`? What type of data is being  transferred? Is it some value which is formatted wrong (e.g. a weird Date) because of his locale?

Comment: @Marc yes, I added breakpoint, but I don't get to it. Nothing is in `/IWFND/ERROR_LOG`, nothing in `ST22`, nothing in `SU53`. It was pending for about a minute, then I lost my patience. No data is transferred, this call should fetch the token if I'm not mistaken, it's the call before the actual POST. This first call is automatically done by the framework. For all other users this call doesn't take longer than half a second.

Comment: Just an idea we recently had: check headers, are they written with different case usage? This recently caused a problem for a CORS action since the receiver was only accepting the Camercase version of the header title. Otherwise I would check for proxies on network settings or try if you can do the same call using postman. Not a lot, but who knows it might help out, good luck.